# How to start an application before Build in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I need some header files for my Visual C++ project. But this header files should be created with an application as programmatically. 
When this header files is created, Visual studio can include this headers for build.

So, I need that : 
 - When I press the "Build button of Visual Studio", an application should be started. 
 - When application is finished, Building should start.

Does Visual studio support this? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can add pre-build steps for VS projects.

Comment: [First hit for googling your question title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyz1h6zd.aspx) includes a link to "Specify custom pre-compile and post-compile actions for a build."

Answer (score 0):

Put your code that needs to be generated/created in a "C++ Class Library" and use this library as a reference in your project.

OR

invoking the compiler (cl.exe) directly from your [Build Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) of Visual Studio.